# Exit not working properly (unity 2d/C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the game, after collecting a certain amount of items you need to get to a door which brings you to the next level.

I tested it where you dont need to get to the door and it works just fine. So idk why it won't work when you need to get to the door.

And for some reason, ">=4" doesn't work it only works with this "<=4" lol.

I would put the code here but idk how to do it so it can be read easily.

Comment: Is the value is `4`? because your condition contain `4` in two state

Comment: @D-Shine  here's a class:   public int itemcollected; (i did try to put the value on there and even tried a private int but nothing worked).  Here's my if statement:    if (itemcollected >= 4) 
                 {
                 
                 SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
                }

Comment: Hello Kris welcome to Stack Overflow.  To add code to your post use the .[edit] link on the lower left of your post (under the tags).  Paste code into the question and then mark the text as code by selecting it and clicking the **Code Sample** icon on the toolbar (it looks like a pair of curly braces **{}**) or type **CTRL+K**.  Alternatively you can do it manually by starting each line of code with four **space** characters.  If you use **TAB** in your code please change those to spaces.  See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more info.

Comment: More hints: you'll probably find reading [tour], [ask] and [mcve] helpful.  Not all Stack Overflow readers are native English speakers so it is generally best to avid using abbreviations like `idk`.

Comment: How are you setting the door as a final goal? with a trigger enter to detect the player once he is in? And yes please, post your code